# How can I call custom javascript on successful webform submissions through hook_form_alter?

Tags: 7, javascript, webforms

I have some custom js code which should be executed after successful webform's submission.

JS Code :

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){ 
    form_submit_telium();
});
```

below approaches, I already tried

1.

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'form_submit_telium');
$page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
ajax_deliver($page);
```

-> It's not working, due to my webform is not submitted through ajax call.

2. 

```
 
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
                drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/form_submit.js',
            );
```

3.

```
 
drupal_add_js("jQuery('document').ready(function(){
      form_submit_telium(); });",'inline');
```

**Webform alter code:**

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $form['#submit'][] = 'telium_form_submit';
}

function telium_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
    // above three approaches
}
```

Please let me know if you have any other approach to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd option will work in that :

.Module

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == "webform_client_form_id"){
        $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'c1') . '/c1.js';
    }
}
```

Js Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#webform-client-form-id" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

as I mention javascript should be execute only when a form is submitted without any error. but it is also executed when form has a custom validation error.

Comment: also, notice that whenever the form is submitted it is redirecting to same page(both cases 1. with error and 2. without error).

Comment: 1.) **Javascript should be call for all webforms**
`function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
 
 if($form_id){
  $form['#submit'][] = 'module_form_submit_handler'; // call custom submit handler function 
 }
}`

Comment: 2.)
`function module_form_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state)
{
 $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/form_submit.js'; 

}`